# JQuery Selector Question -- How to find all HREF's with a target = _blank?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

My "JQuery Selector Foo" stinks.  I need to find all HREF's with a target attr of _blank and replace them with a common window/target.  Assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Got an answer in less than 1 minute.  Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$("a[target='_blank']").attr('target', 'sometarget');
```

Do you mean something like that?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
        $("a[target=_blank]").each(function () {
            var href = $(this).attr("href"); // retrive href foreach a
            $(this).attr("href", "something_you_want"); // replace href attribute with wich u want
            // etc
        });
```

let me know what do you want, for more help

Answer (score 0):

If you're specifically looking for `href` values which have blank values then do the following

```
$('a[href=""]').each(function() {
  $(a).attr('href', 'theNewUrl');
});
```

This will catch only anchor tags which have a href attribute that is empty.  It won't work though for anchors lacking an href tag

```
<a href="">Link 1</a> <!-- Works -->
<a>Link 2</a> <!-- Won't work -->
```

If you need to match the latter then do the following

```
$('a').each(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href') || '';
  if (href === '') {
    $(this).attr('href', 'theNewUrl');
  }
});
```